# Accessing json array fields that are nested

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am able to get my first json field set "conferences" :"name" "conferences" :"alias" to show up in html but I cannot seem to access the arrays that are deeply nested in the array. These are arrays which contains   "division" :"name" and "division" :"alias", "teams" :"name" and "teams" :"market",  and "rank" :"conference" and "rank":"division", and "rank":"clinched". First I'll post the basic one that works as this is the template for my javascript. But then how do I add on to it to get the returned values that I am looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#get-data').click(function () {
    var showData = $('#show-data');

    $.getJSON('rankings.json', function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        var conferences = data.conferences.map(function (conferences) {
            return conferences.name + ': ' + conferences.alias;
        });

        showData.empty();

        if (conferences.length) {
            var content = '<li>' + conferences.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
            var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
            showData.append(list);
        }


    });

    showData.text('Loading the JSON file.');
});
});
```

Below Here is the Json.

```
te{

"conferences": [{
    "id": "3960cfac-7361-4b30-bc25-8d393de6f62f",
    "name": "EASTERN CONFERENCE",
    "alias": "EASTERN",
    "divisions": [{
        "id": "582d6502-9a93-4a8d-8785-69374d732875",
        "name": "Atlantic",
        "alias": "ATLANTIC",
        "teams": [{
            "id": "583ecda6-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Raptors",
            "market": "Toronto",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 4,
                "division": 1,
                "clinched": "division"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583eccfa-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Celtics",
            "market": "Boston",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 7,
                "division": 2,
                "clinched": "playoff_berth"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ec9d6-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Nets",
            "market": "Brooklyn",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 8,
                "division": 3,
                "clinched": "playoff_berth"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ec87d-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "76ers",
            "market": "Philadelphia",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 14,
                "division": 4,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ec70e-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Knicks",
            "market": "New York",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 15,
                "division": 5,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "f3aaf23a-1ceb-46ef-8fef-9403692e801b",
        "name": "Central",
        "alias": "CENTRAL",
        "teams": [{
            "id": "583ec773-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Cavaliers",
            "market": "Cleveland",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 2,
                "division": 1,
                "clinched": "division"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ec5fd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Bulls",
            "market": "Chicago",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 3,
                "division": 2,
                "clinched": "playoff_berth"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ecefd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Bucks",
            "market": "Milwaukee",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 6,
                "division": 3,
                "clinched": "playoff_berth"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ec7cd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Pacers",
            "market": "Indiana",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 9,
                "division": 4,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ec928-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Pistons",
            "market": "Detroit",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 12,
                "division": 5,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "54dc7348-c1d2-40d8-88b3-c4c0138e085d",
        "name": "Southeast",
        "alias": "SOUTHEAST",
        "teams": [{
            "id": "583ecb8f-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Hawks",
            "market": "Atlanta",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 1,
                "division": 1,
                "clinched": "conference"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ec8d4-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Wizards",
            "market": "Washington",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 5,
                "division": 2,
                "clinched": "playoff_berth"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ecea6-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Heat",
            "market": "Miami",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 10,
                "division": 3,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ec97e-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Hornets",
            "market": "Charlotte",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 11,
                "division": 4,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ed157-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Magic",
            "market": "Orlando",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 13,
                "division": 5,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "id": "7fe7e212-de01-4f8f-a31d-b9f0a95731e3",
    "name": "WESTERN CONFERENCE",
    "alias": "WESTERN",
    "divisions": [{
        "id": "12bf14ba-eb16-4c6f-8275-e801b6947c1e",
        "name": "Northwest",
        "alias": "NORTHWEST",
        "teams": [{
            "id": "583ed056-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Trail Blazers",
            "market": "Portland",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 4,
                "division": 1,
                "clinched": "division"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ecfff-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Thunder",
            "market": "Oklahoma City",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 9,
                "division": 2,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ece50-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Jazz",
            "market": "Utah",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 11,
                "division": 3,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ed102-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Nuggets",
            "market": "Denver",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 12,
                "division": 4,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583eca2f-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Timberwolves",
            "market": "Minnesota",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 15,
                "division": 5,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "f074cb3e-90cf-42e1-8067-cdbcd99ec230",
        "name": "Pacific",
        "alias": "PACIFIC",
        "teams": [{
            "id": "583ec825-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Warriors",
            "market": "Golden State",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 1,
                "division": 1,
                "clinched": "conference"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ecdfb-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Clippers",
            "market": "Los Angeles",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 3,
                "division": 2,
                "clinched": "playoff_berth"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ecfa8-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Suns",
            "market": "Phoenix",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 10,
                "division": 3,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ed0ac-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Kings",
            "market": "Sacramento",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 13,
                "division": 4,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ecae2-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Lakers",
            "market": "Los Angeles",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 14,
                "division": 5,
                "clinched": "eliminated"
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "1d29f94c-9587-494b-a232-feb20a40eb4c",
        "name": "Southwest",
        "alias": "SOUTHWEST",
        "teams": [{
            "id": "583ecb3a-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Rockets",
            "market": "Houston",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 2,
                "division": 1,
                "clinched": "division"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583eca88-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Grizzlies",
            "market": "Memphis",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 5,
                "division": 2,
                "clinched": "playoff_berth"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ecd4f-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Spurs",
            "market": "San Antonio",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 6,
                "division": 3,
                "clinched": "playoff_berth"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ecf50-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Mavericks",
            "market": "Dallas",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 7,
                "division": 4,
                "clinched": "playoff_berth"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "583ecc9a-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
            "name": "Pelicans",
            "market": "New Orleans",
            "rank": {
                "conference": 8,
                "division": 5,
                "clinched": "playoff_berth"
            }
        }]
    }]
}]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but maybe you would like to get a tree-like structure in HTML?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#get-data').click(function () {
        var showData = $('#show-data');

        $.getJSON('rankings.json', function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            var conferences = data.conferences.map(function (conference) {
                var conf = $('<li />').text(conference.name + ': '+ conference.alias);
                var divisions = conference.divisions.map(function (division) {
                    var divisionLi = $('<li />').text(division.name + ': '+ division.alias);
                    var teams = division.teams.map(function (team) {
                        return $('<li />').text(team.name + 
                            ': '+ team.market + ' | ' + 
                            team.rank.conference + ' : ' + 
                            team.rank.division + ' : ' + 
                            team.rank.clinched);
                    });
                    $('<ul />').html(teams).appendTo(divisionLi);
                    return divisionLi;
                });
                $('<ul />').html(divisions).appendTo(conf);
                return conf;
            });

            showData.empty();

            if (conferences.length) {
                var list = $('<ul />').html(conferences);
                showData.append(list);
            }


        });

        showData.text('Loading the JSON file.');
    });
});
```

Comment: This that was it! I was trying to figure out how to put it all together. You did. I hope I can upvote you and you can do the same. Kudos!